# How to Add Default Value in Angular Selection Form

Tags: angular, forms, default-value

I am currently facing a problem when setting a default value for a selection as part of a form in the latest Angular version.

Please find below the code of the selection:

```
<select name="membershipType" [(ngModel)]="membership.membershipType">
<option *ngFor="let type of membershipTypes" [ngValue]="type" >{{type.type}}</option></select>
```

To explain a bit more on the background:

- I have two arrays in my .ts file, 1st being "membership" and the 2nd being "membershipTypes"
- I would like to display "membership.membershipType" as the default value
- The data for the options are the values of the 2nd array "membershipType"
- The selected "membershipType" shall be passed to "membership.membershipType"
- **Current status: selected "membershipType" is correctly passed but no default value is shown**

Any help would be highly appreciated (as I tried a lot of different solutions that did not work), thanks a lot!

Comment: > "as I tried a lot of different solutions that did not work" --> Please show what you tried

Comment: I am fairly new to Angular so I do not know if some of them are even related to default values but I tried: 
- splitting [(ngModel)] to [ngModel] and (ngChangeModel)
- defaultSelected
- [attr.value] in combination with [attr.selected]
...

I was just able to narrow it down to the problem that - in the dropdown - I would like to display a field of "membershipTypes" which is called type and returns a string. However, the value in [(ngModel)] is the object and not that field in the object which leads to the system not being able to select the default...

Comment: `membership.membershipType` can you provide the value of this and `type` ?

Comment: Sure, "membership.membershipType" is an object of "membershipType" which contains an id, "type" as string and "price" as number. Thus, the "type" is just a text for humans to identify the different membership types. For the background: membership is a table in the backend as well as membershipType. The membership table has a field for referencing a membershipType. The form I am working on allows the user to change the membershipType of a membership which will call a REST-PUT